# How is it solved: $\sin(x) + \sin(3x) + \sin(5x) +\dotsb + \sin(2n - 1)x =$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

The problem is to find the summary of this statement:
$$\sin(x) + \sin(3x) + \sin(5x) + \dotsb + \sin(2n - 1)x =  $$

I've tried to rewrite all sinuses as complex numbers but it was in vain. I suppose there is much more complicated method to do this. I think it may be solved somehow using complex numbers or progressoins.

How it's solved using complex numbers or even without them if possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bad title . Not using mathjax . Homework question .

Comment: use Euler identity $e^{it}=cos(t)+isin(t)$ and geometric series.

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: [MSE-MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) Tutorial.

Answer (score 9):

Note that we wish to evaluate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n\sin((2k-1)x)$.  Then, using the addition angle law, we have

$$\sin(x)\sin((2k-1)x)=\frac12\left(\cos(2(k-1)x)-\cos(2kx)\right)$$

Now, sum the telescoping series and divide by $\sin(x)$.

Comment: Does that telescope?

Comment: @martycohen It does now.  Thank you for the catch!

Comment: @egreg Your edit had a flaw in it.

Comment: @Dr.MV Now I see it, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:**

Your complex sum is:
$$S=e^{ix}+e^{3ix}+....e^{(2n-1)ix}=e^{ix}\frac{  1-e^{2inx } }{  1-e^{2ix}  }$$

then you take the imaginary part.

You will obtain

$$\frac{   \sin^2(nx) }{  \sin(x)   }$$

with the condition  $x\neq k\pi$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Dr.MV This is quite easy as well; the trick is to collect $e^{inx}$ from the numerator and $e^{ix}$ from the denominator. Piece of cake. `;-)`

Comment: @Dr.MV Provided you remember the product-to-sum formula. `;-)` I always have to look it up.

Comment: Furthermore, you can have two sums for  the price of one…

Comment: @Bernard, do you refer to Dr. MV solution? I would rather word it backwords: One solution to the price two sums. I found that more mathematician like, contra intuitive, but "true" just like: 1 guy enters the house, 2 leave, now 1 has to enter for it to be empty..

Comment: @Imago: No, I was alluding to Abdallah Hammam's solution.  I love the logic (Lewis Carroll or Marx Brothers?)